# Alternative component or bug solution

Tags: powerbi

here an original XY chart plus median as center line, and the change to "with bullets"
[image: original]
[image: showmaker]

**The result below is a bug: how to solve it?**
[image: with-bullets]

Comment: Why are there two y-axes and why did the scale change on the right axis between the screenshots?

Comment: Hi @AlexisOlson, I removed the second y-axis, but the *bug* persist.

Comment: This is pretty strange-looking. Can you create a sample file that exhibits this behavior?

Answer (score 2):

Your median line looks like it was added via the Legend or Values well - it wasn't created using the Analytics / Median feature.  Probably the field or measure you are using for the Median is producing unexpected results.

I would use the Analytics pane to add a Median line:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/desktop-analytics-pane

There doesn't appear to be any "bug" triggered by the Show markers option.  I was able to build a quick repro (using Analytics / Median) and it looks fine with markers either off or on:

[image]